# How to show icon in the notification text Area in android

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-remoteview

I have a simple query , whose answer i do not seem to get from anywhere.
I have a notification like below

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder= new NotificationCompat.Builder(baseContext).setLargeIcon(large_icon)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.message_received_small_icon)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(soundUri);
mBuilder.setContentText(_summaryText);

        notification = mBuilder.build();
```

I know setContentText will set message say M, the user want to show on the notification.
My question is is there any way i can show an icon with the message M. 
I want to show an icon to left of message . Is that possible with default notification. I have been stuck at it for a long time.

I can create a custom remoteview for displaying the icon . But As android versions are updating , each version has a different style of notification . So if i use custom layout for notification , then i will need to create custom view for all android versions, which i want as a last option.

Please help if it is possible with currently available styles.

Answer (score 0):

in your notification builder set large icon will set the icon in left of your notification message.

```
  mBuilder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                    R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
```

Comment: I am not talking about the large icon. I think you misunderstood the question . Basically i want to show an icon where setContentText is shown.

Answer (score 0):

To display larger images/icons, you need to set custom remote view and customize your layout.xml.

**To add small Emoji icons you can just add icon's Unicode into string**.
To find Emoji icons go to here: https://emojipedia.org/google/

Example:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
        .setContentTitle("Your Title")
        .setContentText("\uD83D\uDCC4  -> This is Page Facing Up emoji icon")
```